# Adding a rewrite rule to a custom post type breaks Divi Theme Builder

Tags: wordpress, themes, divi

I am building out a business listings site and the client wants the city to be in the URL. So I created a rewrite rule to do this and it works great. The problem is now my Theme Builder doesn't work. If I comment out the *add_rewrite_rule* line of code Theme Builder works fine.

I have tried Divi Safe Mode and Theme Builder works. Of course it does because there's no rewrite rules. I also tried my child theme with zero plugins enabled, fully updated WordPress and Divi, but still the Theme Builder does not work if the *add_rewrite_rule* code is active.

Here is the code in question. I installed this code on a completely different site and had the same issue.

```
$slug = 'listings';
$Title = 'Listing';
$Titles = 'Listings';
$titles = 'listings';

$labels = [
    'name'                       => _x($Titles, 'Taxonomy General Name', $text_domain),
    'singular_name'              => _x($Title, 'Taxonomy Singular Name', $text_domain),
    'menu_name'                  => __($Titles, $text_domain),
    'all_items'                  => __('All ' . $Titles, $text_domain),
    'parent_item'                => __('Parent ' . $Title, $text_domain),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __('Parent ' . $Title . ':', $text_domain),
    'new_item_name'              => __('New ' . $Title . ' Name', $text_domain),
    'add_new_item'               => __('Add New ' . $Title, $text_domain),
    'edit_item'                  => __('Edit ' . $Title, $text_domain),
    'update_item'                => __('Update ' . $Title, $text_domain),
    'view_item'                  => __('View ' . $Title, $text_domain),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate ' . $titles . ' with commas', $text_domain),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Add or remove ' . $titles, $text_domain),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from the most used', $text_domain),
    'popular_items'              => __('Popular ' . $Titles, $text_domain),
    'search_items'               => __('Search ' . $Titles, $text_domain),
    'not_found'                  => __('Not Found', $text_domain),
    'no_terms'                   => __('No ' . $Titles, $text_domain),
    'items_list'                 => __($Titles . ' list', $text_domain),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __($Titles . ' list navigation', $text_domain),
];
$args = [
    'label'         => __($Title, $text_domain),
    'description'   => __('Custom post type', $text_domain),
    'menu_position' => 4,
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'supports'      => ['title', 'thumbnail'],
    'taxonomies'    => ['post_tag', 'category'],
    'public'        => TRUE,
    'has_archive'   => TRUE,
    'rewrite'       => TRUE,
];

register_post_type($slug, $args);

add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '([^&]+)', 'city=');
add_rewrite_rule(
    '([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=listings&city=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: Divi Support has dubbed this a "developer issue" and will not provide support for it.  Any help with this would be much appreciated. Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I have another helper class that creates a custom post type very similar to Listings called Staff. The add_rewrite_rule for this custom post type does NOT break the Theme Builder. Very strange. It must be something in my ListingHelper class.

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE: I modified my add_rewrite_rule so it does not use a wildcard for the first part of the regex (see note above). This seems to work, but I need to allow a wildcard to be in that first part.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to this issue was to add a string to the beginning of my regex.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'listings/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=listings&city=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Apparently, having a wildcard prefix in the add_rewrite_rule breaks Divi's Theme Builder. I'm guessing that it has something to do with how the Theme Builder handles rewrites in order to create specific templates. I'm going to have to create 301 redirects for all existing listings now, but the Theme Builder works.